# How to animate button in android?

Tags: android, animation, button, shake

I am making an android app, and I have a button which leads to a messaging place. On the activity with the button, I check if there is any unread messages, and if so I want to do something to the button to let the user know that there is something unread.

I was thinking of having the button sorta vibrate horizontally like 3 shakes every 2 or 3 seconds.

I know how to run a thread in the background which does something every x milliseconds. But what I don't know what to do is shake it horizontally 3 times.

Can anyone help with this?

I was thinking of using the sin function, for the animation, I can use output from a sin function to get values that go up and down, which I can set the horizontal position of the button... But this seems too extreme, is there a better way?

Comment: do u want animation or button press effect ??

Answer (score 32):

I can't comment on @omega's comment because I don't have enough reputation but the answer to that question should be something like:

**shake.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="100"          <!-- how long the animation lasts -->
    android:fromDegrees="-5"        <!-- how far to swing left -->
    android:pivotX="50%"            <!-- pivot from horizontal center -->
    android:pivotY="50%"            <!-- pivot from vertical center -->
    android:repeatCount="10"        <!-- how many times to swing back and forth -->
    android:repeatMode="reverse"    <!-- to make the animation go the other way -->
    android:toDegrees="5" />        <!-- how far to swing right -->
```

**Class.java**

```
Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
view.startAnimation(shake);
```

This is just one way of doing what you want, there may be better methods out there.

Comment: How can I shake it horizontally?

Answer (score 28):

create shake.xml in anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:fromXDelta="0" 
        android:toXDelta="10" 
            android:duration="1000" 
                android:interpolator="@anim/cycle" />
```

and cycle.xml in anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cycleInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:cycles="4" />
```

now add  animation on your code

```
Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
anyview.startAnimation(shake);
```

If you want vertical animation, change fromXdelta  and toXdelta value to fromYdelta and toYdelta value

Comment: This just makes it moves `right` then instantly goes back to original position 4 times, but how do I get it to move `right` and then `left`, then `right` then `left` back to original position like a shake effect?

Comment: how to make this animation happen continuously?

Comment: This answer is helpful for me to implement shake like animation in android.

Comment: hey @RVG thanks for the code, but how do I change the shaking speed?

Answer (score 6):

---

**Class.Java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_with_the_button);

    final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.milkshake);
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_game_btn);
    myButton.setAnimation(myAnim);
}
```

For *onClick* of the Button

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.startAnimation(myAnim);
    }
});
```

---

Create the ***anim*** folder in ***res*** directory

Right click on, *res -> New -> Directory*

Name the new Directory ***anim***

create a new xml file name it ***milkshake***

---

**milkshake.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromDegrees="-5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="10"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toDegrees="5" />
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

public class HeightAnimation extends Animation {
    protected final int originalHeight;
    protected final View view;
    protected float perValue;

    public HeightAnimation(View view, int fromHeight, int toHeight) {
        this.view = view;
        this.originalHeight = fromHeight;
        this.perValue = (toHeight - fromHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (originalHeight + perValue * interpolatedTime);
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

uss to:

```
HeightAnimation heightAnim = new HeightAnimation(view, view.getHeight(), viewPager.getHeight() - otherView.getHeight());
heightAnim.setDuration(1000);
view.startAnimation(heightAnim);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Dependency

Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    ...
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}}
```

and then add dependency
`dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.varunest:sparkbutton:1.0.5'
}`

### Usage

#### XML

```
<com.varunest.sparkbutton.SparkButton
        android:id="@+id/spark_button"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:sparkbutton_activeImage="@drawable/active_image"
        app:sparkbutton_inActiveImage="@drawable/inactive_image"
        app:sparkbutton_iconSize="40dp"
        app:sparkbutton_primaryColor="@color/primary_color"
        app:sparkbutton_secondaryColor="@color/secondary_color" />
```

#### Java (Optional)

```
SparkButton button  = new SparkButtonBuilder(context)
            .setActiveImage(R.drawable.active_image)
            .setInActiveImage(R.drawable.inactive_image)
            .setDisabledImage(R.drawable.disabled_image)
            .setImageSizePx(getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.button_size))
            .setPrimaryColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary_color))
            .setSecondaryColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.secondary_color))
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Kotlin**, this way after XML:

Define a View:

```
 val playDel = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.player_del)
```

Find a Animation: Here from Android Lib

```
val imgAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out)
```

Connect to the View

```
 playDel.animation=imgAnim
```

Answer (score 0):

First create shake.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="100"          
    android:fromDegrees="-5"        
    android:pivotX="50%"            
    android:pivotY="50%"            
    android:repeatCount="10"        
    android:repeatMode="reverse"    
    android:toDegrees="5" />
```

Class.java

```
Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
view.startAnimation(shake);
```